# Traslate в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Здравствуйте! Есть объект, который поворачивается и градус его поворота запоминается, но затем захотел сделать его перемещение при сохраненном повороте, в принципе все очевидно(казалось мне). Траслейтил в середину объекта и поворачивал, а вот как дальше его перенести в нужную сторону? Заранее благодарен.
Есть такой код:

Comment: все трансформации происходят относительно отрисованного положения... если Вы сначала повернули и перенесли, а потом опять хотите перенести, то необходимо учесть все предыдущие трансформации. transform="translate(x+x0 y+y0) rotate(angle+angle0 cx cy)

Comment: Не понимаю в чём проблема, попробуйте полный (минимальный) пример как [code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) добавить (кнопка слева от нумерованного списка), чтобы наглядно проблему продемонстрировать.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю, подскажите, есть ли здесь возможность узнать положение на экране картинки? Мне нужно узнать Y, а я без понятия, так он не добавляется в DOM и прочие штуки с ним не прокатят, а мышь у меня не  участвует

Comment: @jfs [Ссылка, код](https://jsfiddle.net/graf_/ta4q0xm4/1/), пытался добавить в пост, добавляется, но все сворачивается, так лучше. Стрелка вверх влево вправо низ, если нажата меньше чем 100мс -быстрый поворот, если зажата кнопка влево/вправо больше чем 100мс,то медленный поворот, ехать вперед кнопка вверх (долго жать), p.s если ездить вдоль оси X(не назад), то поворот не скачет, если же подняться в угол или вообще по Y то скачет, я не знаю как его вычислить

Comment: @recovery добавил код из комментария в вопрос. Пример не минимальный. [mcve]. Чтобы c середины начать, вместо `x = 300`, попробуйте что-нибудь типа: `x = (canvas.width - tank.width) / 2` (аналогично для y)